# Get a @JsonProperty by name

Tags: java, jackson

I have a Jackson annotated Java class

```
public class MyClass {
    @JsonProperty String foo;
    @JsonProperty Optional<Integer> bar;
}
```

This class is created by Spring Boot from the JSON of a HTTP request body. Some fields, such as `bar`, might not be present in the JSON. The JSON is not available at this stage.

I would like to fetch `foo` and `bar` given their string names, after checking whether they are present in the object.

```
void doSomething (MyClass obj) {
    for (String s : {"foo", "bar"}) {
        if (object_contains (obj, s)) {
           Object value = get_value_by_name (obj, s);
           // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Given that `"foo"` and `"bar"` are given as strings, how can I write `object_contains` and `get_value_by_name`?

Comment: Java is not like JavaScript, where objects may or may not have certain fields / properties, so the idea "whether a property is present" does not apply to Java. Unless you mean whether the value of the property is `null`. You can use [reflection](https://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection) to dynamically find fields.

Comment: If you want this much dynamism in analyzing your payload you could consider deserializing to a Map.class first and use the implicit keys and contains methods to check for your payload BEFORE then deciding on what your ultimate actual concrete Jackson annotated class should be

Comment: Take a look on similar question [Json to POJO null field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67833795/json-to-pojo-null-field/67836912#67836912). There is a difference between `field is not available` and `field is available but set to null`.